# onEdit() to trigger on specific cell change stopped working

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have an apps script that should be triggered when a specific cell is changed to a specific value. When this happens it should trigger another function that submits data to another sheet, it then also clears the content of the cell that triggers the onEdit function as this lets me now it works and that the data has been sent. This is instead of having a button, since I need it to work on my phone as well.

This worked perfectly fine for a couple of weeks and then suddenly stopped working. The submitData function works fine if I run it separately but the onEdit function doesn't work at all, nothing happens when I edit the cell and nothing happens when I run it from the script editor either.

This is my code:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var ss        = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var formSS    = ss.getSheetByName("Entry Form"); //Form Sheet
  if (e.range.getA1Notation() == 'B41') {
    if (/^\w+$/.test("TRUE")) {        
      eval(submitData)();
      e.range.clearContent();
    }
  }
}
```

I´ve tried a few other things I've found online but to no avail.

Comment: About `This worked perfectly fine for a couple of weeks and then suddenly stopped working.`, what have you done in the script or Spreadsheet? And, in your script, it seems that the edited cell is required to be "B41". Is this related to your current issue? And, how about confirming the sheet name, again? If these were not related to your current issue, can you provide the detailed flow for correctly replicating your current issue?

Comment: I haven't made any major changes that I can remember, that was my first thought. The sheet name is the same and the cell ("B41") is still the same. It's only that cell that I want to monitor and trigger the submitData function, it's a checkbox that works like a button.

"If these were not related to your current issue, can you provide the detailed flow for correctly replicating your current issue?"

Not sure exactly what you mean, care to elaborate? When I edit the cell, nothing happens, it doesn't trigger the onEdit function.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize for my poor English skill.

Answer (score 0):

I'm an idiot, or maybe only a beginner, or both... I had two onEdit() functions as I was under the impression that would work, but it turns out the second one overwrites the first one. I merged them and now it works.